# Select - get previous and new value only on change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with a few select boxes on, my objective is to capture the previous value and the new value which I've managed to achieve in the code below.
This builds up a one to one pairing of arrays so array position 0 for previous should be the previous value for the new value in array position 0 of updates. There is server side processing to validate the data passed  back so this part doesn't worry me too much.

The problem is - if a user clicks on the select box the focus event is thrown, I capture the previous value, if the user then decides to stay on the same value they just click back on it and the change event is not thrown which puts my array out of sync and leaves me with a false previous value (if it doesn't change I don't need to capture it as previous).

Have I overcomplicated? Any suggestions or points around better handling the user selecting the same value would be appreciated.

```
var updates = [];
var previous = [];

    $("select").on('focus', function () {
        item = {};
        item["id"] = this.value;
        item["name"] =  $(this).find('option:selected').text();
        previous.push(item);

    }).change(function() {
        item = {};
        item["id"] = this.value;
        item["name"] = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
        updates.push(item);
    });
```

Thanks to the pointer from the answer below I've ended up with the following code;

### Final working code

```
var updates = [];

$("select").on('focus', function () {
    item = {};
    item["id"] = this.value;
    item["name"] =  $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    updates.push(item);

}).change(function() {
    if (updates.length > 1) {
        updates = updates.slice(updates.length-1,updates.length);
    }
    previousPos = updates.length-1;
    newItem = {};
    updates[previousPos]["newid"] = this.value;
    updates[previousPos]["newname"] = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    $(this).blur();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/update',
        data: JSON.stringify(updates)
    });
});
```

I'm handling CSRF token setup elsewhere with ajaxSetup.

Comment: PS: you are declaring your variables elsewhere with `var` aren't you? :)

Comment: Hah, well spotted. Yeah they were declared further up from this code so when I copy/pasted the bulk, I just typed those in :) Updated

Comment: Did you try initializing the item variable with the value in the dropdown? That way if the on change function is not invoked , you will have the value that is shown on the screen in the item variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you just push to one array instead of two. This way you can get the array length/count to determine if there was a previously selected option?

```
if(item.length >= 2 ){
// do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the pointer i needed. I ended up changing my model completely, rather than populating two arrays with all page changes I now just use ajax to submit each change as it happens. All I've done is add a check in the on change to slice off the start of the array if its longer than 1 (as in, it has more than the previous value. I'll update my question with the final code.